# Flutter build on Windows fails to create release, after upgrading to Flutter 3.10.0

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, build

When I try to build release version of my app for Windows, using Flutter 3.10.0, I receive this error:

```
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_filesystem_desktop_windows.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter
```

Comment: apparently there is no official windows support yet https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10171#issuecomment-1379685823